# Can't understand why this code give different results in different versions of python

Tags: python

Some time ago I found this code which calculate digits of pi:

```
def pi_digits():
    """generator for digits of pi"""
    q,r,t,k,n,l = 1,0,1,1,3,3
    while True:
        if 4*q+r-t < n*t:
            yield n
            q,r,t,k,n,l = (10*q,10*(r-n*t),t,k,(10*(3*q+r))/t-10*n,l)
        else:
            q,r,t,k,n,l = (q*k,(2*q+r)*l,t*l,k+1,(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)/(t*l),l+2)
digits = pi_digits()
for i in range(30): print digits.next()
```

and now I want to use it in Python 3.4 and I made a little change:

```
def pi():
    '''Generator for digits of pi'''
    q,r,t,k,n,l = 1,0,1,1,3,3
    while True:
        if 4*q+r-t < n*t:
            yield n
            q,r,t,k,n,l = (10*q,10*(r-n*t),t,k,(10*(3*q+r))/t-10*n,l)
        else:
            q,r,t,k,n,l = (q*k,(2*q+r)*l,t*l,k+1,(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)/(t*l),l+2)

def main():
    a=pi()
    i=30
    while i>0:
        print(next(a))
        i-=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But my code prints wrong result,like:

```
3.0,
1.0476190476190477,
3.272283272283272,
3.6476767126921925,
4.078229842128079,
4.6365352277262,
5.345159217838377,
6.228740292622248,
7.819098709270982,
4.255764551767985,
5.069552326563916,
6.0642804719748575...
```

So what makes difference?

Comment: Fix the indent please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the difference is in your division.  In Python 2, dividing one integer by another produces an integer.  In Python 3, it produces a float.  I believe you can use the `//` operator in place of `/` to achieve the desired behavior in Python 3.